# Jquery Initialize (for beginner!)

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem with smoothscroll. I am using anchors on a single page, and it all works great except on the first link clicked, it just jumps to the anchor, instead of using the smoothscroll, now, Im no good with Jquery, but I imagine i would need to Initialize the script before anything is clicked, rather than have it initialized on the first click. Could anyone help me with this?

I assume this is to be used, but what code does this refer to (put your CODE here)?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Put your code here
});
```

here is the js itself.

```
/**
 * SmoothScroll
 * This helper script created by DWUser.com.  Copyright 2012 DWUser.com.  
 * Dual-licensed under the GPL and MIT licenses.  
 * All individual scripts remain property of their copyrighters.
 * Date: 10-Sep-2012
 * Version: 1.0.1
 */
if (!window['jQuery']) alert('The jQuery library must be included before the smoothscroll.js file.  The plugin will not work propery.');

/**
 * jQuery.ScrollTo - Easy element scrolling using jQuery.
 * Copyright (c) 2007-2012 Ariel Flesler - aflesler(at)gmail(dot)com | http://flesler.blogspot.com
 * Dual licensed under MIT and GPL.
 * @author Ariel Flesler
 * @version 1.4.3.1
 */
;(function($){var h=$.scrollTo=function(a,b,c){$(window).scrollTo(a,b,c)};h.defaults={axis:'xy',duration:parseFloat($.fn.jquery)>=1.3?0:1,limit:true};h.window=function(a){return $(window)._scrollable()};$.fn._scrollable=function(){return this.map(function(){var a=this,isWin=!a.nodeName||$.inArray(a.nodeName.toLowerCase(),['iframe','#document','html','body'])!=-1;if(!isWin)return a;var b=(a.contentWindow||a).document||a.ownerDocument||a;return/webkit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)||b.compatMode=='BackCompat'?b.body:b.documentElement})};$.fn.scrollTo=function(e,f,g){if(typeof f=='object'){g=f;f=0}if(typeof g=='function')g={onAfter:g};if(e=='max')e=9e9;g=$.extend({},h.defaults,g);f=f||g.duration;g.queue=g.queue&&g.axis.length>1;if(g.queue)f/=2;g.offset=both(g.offset);g.over=both(g.over);return this._scrollable().each(function(){if(e==null)return;var d=this,$elem=$(d),targ=e,toff,attr={},win=$elem.is('html,body');switch(typeof targ){case'number':case'string':if(/^([+-]=)?\d+(\.\d+)?(px|%)?$/.test(targ)){targ=both(targ);break}targ=$(targ,this);if(!targ.length)return;case'object':if(targ.is||targ.style)toff=(targ=$(targ)).offset()}$.each(g.axis.split(''),function(i,a){var b=a=='x'?'Left':'Top',pos=b.toLowerCase(),key='scroll'+b,old=d[key],max=h.max(d,a);if(toff){attr[key]=toff[pos]+(win?0:old-$elem.offset()[pos]);if(g.margin){attr[key]-=parseInt(targ.css('margin'+b))||0;attr[key]-=parseInt(targ.css('border'+b+'Width'))||0}attr[key]+=g.offset[pos]||0;if(g.over[pos])attr[key]+=targ[a=='x'?'width':'height']()*g.over[pos]}else{var c=targ[pos];attr[key]=c.slice&&c.slice(-1)=='%'?parseFloat(c)/100*max:c}if(g.limit&&/^\d+$/.test(attr[key]))attr[key]=attr[key]<=0?0:Math.min(attr[key],max);if(!i&&g.queue){if(old!=attr[key])animate(g.onAfterFirst);delete attr[key]}});animate(g.onAfter);function animate(a){$elem.animate(attr,f,g.easing,a&&function(){a.call(this,e,g)})}}).end()};h.max=function(a,b){var c=b=='x'?'Width':'Height',scroll='scroll'+c;if(!$(a).is('html,body'))return a[scroll]-$(a)[c.toLowerCase()]();var d='client'+c,html=a.ownerDocument.documentElement,body=a.ownerDocument.body;return Math.max(html[scroll],body[scroll])-Math.min(html[d],body[d])};function both(a){return typeof a=='object'?a:{top:a,left:a}}})(jQuery);

/**
 * jQuery.LocalScroll
 * Copyright (c) 2007-2010 Ariel Flesler - aflesler(at)gmail(dot)com | http://flesler.blogspot.com
 * Dual licensed under MIT and GPL.
 * Date: 05/31/2010
 * @author Ariel Flesler
 * @version 1.2.8b
 **/
;(function(b){function g(a,e,d){var h=e.hash.slice(1),f=document.getElementById(h)||document.getElementsByName(h)[0];if(f){a&&a.preventDefault();var c=b(d.target);if(!(d.lock&&c.is(":animated")||d.onBefore&&!1===d.onBefore(a,f,c))){d.stop&&c._scrollable().stop(!0);if(d.hash){var a=f.id==h?"id":"name",g=b("<a> </a>").attr(a,h).css({position:"absolute",top:b(window).scrollTop(),left:b(window).scrollLeft()});f[a]="";b("body").prepend(g);location=e.hash;g.remove();f[a]=h}c.scrollTo(f,d).trigger("notify.serialScroll",
[f])}}}var i=location.href.replace(/#.*/,""),c=b.localScroll=function(a){b("body").localScroll(a)};c.defaults={duration:1E3,axis:"y",event:"click",stop:!0,target:window,reset:!0};c.hash=function(a){if(location.hash){a=b.extend({},c.defaults,a);a.hash=!1;if(a.reset){var e=a.duration;delete a.duration;b(a.target).scrollTo(0,a);a.duration=e}g(0,location,a)}};b.fn.localScroll=function(a){function e(){return!!this.href&&!!this.hash&&this.href.replace(this.hash,"")==i&&(!a.filter||b(this).is(a.filter))}
a=b.extend({},c.defaults,a);return a.lazy?this.bind(a.event,function(d){var c=b([d.target,d.target.parentNode]).filter(e)[0];c&&g(d,c,a)}):this.find("a,area").filter(e).bind(a.event,function(b){g(b,this,a)}).end().end()}})(jQuery);

// Initialize all .smoothScroll links
jQuery(function($){ $.localScroll({filter:'.smoothScroll'}); });
```

The HTML -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>The Lantern</title>
    <meta name="description" content=" " />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image" href="img/site/favicon.jpg" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/smoothscroll.js"></script> 

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.076848, 4.275590);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'The Lantern'
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="fix" class="noIbar">
<div class="nav">
<ul>
<li><a class="smoothScroll" id="dot" href="index.html#home">.</a></li>
<li><a class="smoothScroll" href="index.html#info">Info</a></li>
<li><a class="smoothScroll" href="index.html#events">Events</a></li>
<li><a class="smoothScroll" href="index.html#menus">Menu's</a></li>
<li><a class="smoothScroll" href="index.html#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div id="home">
<img class="logo" src="img/site/thelantern.png" width="40%"/>

<a id="social" href="http://www.facebook.com/thelanternthehague" target="_blank"><img src="img/site/fb.png" width="100%"/></a>

</div>

<div id="info">
<div class="inner1">
<div class="paraleft">
<h1 class="h1">Info</h1>
<p>
<br/>
The Lantern is a friendly neighbourhood cafe for locals and expats alike, we opened our doors in mid May and are busy welcoming new faces every day for evening drinks, tasty food or just a relaxed cup of coffee. Families with children are welcome, as are well behaved dogs.
We offer the possibility to book our cafe for larger groups or special occasions, if you are looking for somewhere to gather for regular meetings or to throw a (dinner) party please <a class="smoothScroll" href="index.html#contact">contact us</a>
</p>
</div>

<img class="time" src="img/site/time.jpg"/>


<div class="picright">
<img src="img/site/lady.jpg" height="100%" width="100%"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="events">
<div class="inner1">
<div class="pararight">
<h1 class="h1">Events</h1>
<p>
<br/>
The Lantern is a friendly neighbourhood cafe for locals and expats alike, we opened our doors in mid May and are busy welcoming new faces every day for evening drinks, tasty food or just a relaxed cup of coffee. Families with children are welcome, as are well behaved dogs.
We offer the possibility to book our cafe for larger groups or special occasions, if you are looking for somewhere to gather for regular meetings or to throw a (dinner) party please contact us
</p>
</div>
<div class="picleft">
<img src="img/site/piano.jpg" height="100%" width="100%"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="menus">
<div class="inner1">
<div class="paraleft">
<h1 class="h1">Menus</h1>
<p>We offer a range of international food and drink.</p>
<a target="_blank" href="pdf/menu.pdf">Food</a>
</div>

<div class="picright">
<img src="img/site/coffee.jpg" height="100%" width="100%"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="contact">
<div class="inner2">
<div id="contactcontain">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>

<form id="contactform" method="POST" action="php/contact.php">
<input class="equal" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Name"><br/><br/>
<input class="equal" type="email" name="email" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Email Address"><br/><br/>
<input class="hide" type="email" name="fake">
<textarea class="equaltall" type="text" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="news">Sign up for newsletter<br/><br/>
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>

</div>
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 1):

Together with http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/ I come to the conclusion that

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Put your code here
});
```

is already included - in a shortened form (which includes a noConflict mode at the same time):

```
jQuery(function($){
// Your jQuery code here, using the $
});
```

as in the last line of code above

```
// Initialize all .smoothScroll links
jQuery(function($){ $.localScroll({filter:'.smoothScroll'}); });
```

Saying that the reason for your problem with click must be somewhere else..

What does your html look like?